# Empty values when trying get Apache beam DataFlow SideInput

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

I Have a simple pipeline that transforms events from Kafka to Big Query.
I want to save all failed rows to Big Query in another table, AND, I want add the origin event, for more information on the error.
BUT, because the BigQuery API send me just the failed row, I need to use some technology to achieve context.
So, I'm using SideInputView, contains a map between row ID and its event, and then when a row is failed to be saved I take its event from the SideInputView.

As a result of all this design. this work 10% from the events. most of the events are getting empty value from side input view map. But I don'

my code:

```
// create view by row id has
 PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> tableRowToInsertView =
                tableRowToInsertCollection
                        .apply(Window.<TableRowWithEvent>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
                                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(10))
                                .accumulatingFiredPanes()
                                .triggering(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()))
                        .apply(MapElements.via(
                                new SimpleFunction<TableRowWithEvent, KV<String, String>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public KV<String, String> apply(TableRowWithEvent input) {
                                        return KV.of(input.getTableRow().get("uuid").toString(), input.getEvent());
                                    }
                                }))
                        .setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of()))
                        .apply("CreateView", View.asMap());



//using later the side input view
  writeResult
                .getFailedInsertsWithErr()
                .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
                .apply("BQ-insert-error-extract", ParDo.of(new BigQueryInsertErrorExtractFn(tableRowToInsertView)).withSideInputs(tableRowToInsertView))
                .apply("BQ-insert-error-write", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                        .to(errTableSpec)
                        .withJsonSchema(errSchema)
                        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

And the transformer function itself, that uses SideInputView

```
public class BigQueryInsertErrorExtractFn extends DoFn<BigQueryInsertError, TableRow> {


private final PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> tableRowToInsertView;


public BigQueryInsertErrorExtractFn(PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> tableRowToInsertView) {
    this.tableRowToInsertView = tableRowToInsertView;
}

@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {

    BigQueryInsertError bigQueryInsertError=context.element();
    TableRow row = bigQueryInsertError.getRow();

    TableRow convertedRow = new TableRow();
    convertedRow.set("table_row", row.toString());
    convertedRow.set("error", bigQueryInsertError.getError().toString());
    convertedRow.set("error_type", ERROR_TYPE.BQ_INSERT);
    convertedRow.set("t", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").format(new Date()));

    Map<String, String> sideInput = context.sideInput(tableRowToInsertView);

    String event = sideInput.get(bigQueryInsertError.getRow().get("uuid").toString());
    if (event != null) {
        convertedRow.set("event", event);
    }

    context.output(convertedRow);

}
```

}

Comment: It's possible that your triggering configuration is causing a race condition. The Beam Programming Guide states that "if the side input has multiple trigger firings, Beam uses the value from the latest trigger firing". It's not obvious to me that Beam gives any guarantee that your record will be emitted in a pane of tableRowToInsertView before the corresponding record has already sent to BigQuery. Perhaps you can create a windowed PCollection that is a direct parent of the view to use as side input, and is also a direct parent of the collection streamed to BigQuery?

Comment: " Perhaps you can create a windowed PCollection that is a direct parent of the view to use as side input, and is also a direct parent of the collection streamed to BigQuery" . can you give me please an example or link, what is parent window?

Comment: My use of "parent" here isn't standard terminology. What I'm suggesting is that you factor out something like `windowedCollection = tableRowToInsertCollection.apply(Window...)` and make sure that both your PCollectionView and your BigQuery output are both created by applying additional transforms from `windowedCollection`.

Comment: That said, there's a user@beam.apache.org thread over the past few days that I think is directly relevant here: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/20d11046d26174969ef44a781e409a1cb9f7c736e605fa40fdf98397@%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E It sounds from that discussion that panes from multiple firings are less deterministic than users probably expect.